# Spring UriComponents thread safety

Tags: spring, thread-safety, uri

I've gone through as much of the source code as I can bear for `UriComponents` and it appears to be thread-safe but was hoping that someone else can confirm this.

Essentially, I am creating a single instance of `UriComponents` using `UriComponentsBuilder`. This instance is shared and used to expand and create various URI's with runtime query/path params. Is this safe?

Answer (score 2):

UriComponents and its sublass (HierarchicalUriComponents) are immutable. Any operation that returns a UriComponents creates a new instance. The state in UriComponents is marked final. So its safe to use it with multiple threads as they wont be able to modify the state.